# Shell command does not work in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins-pipeline

My shell command works when run in the terminal, but not in a Jenkins pipeline; when the pipeline runs `test.sh`, the shell is run, but the bug service is not. Why is that, and how can I fix this?

`run.sh`:

```
nohup /usr/local/java/1.8/bin/java -Dspring.cloud.config.profile=test -Dspring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888/ -cp /data/jcpt/service/service-account/jar/.:/data/jcpt/service/service-account/jar/lib/* com.caifubao.jcpt.account.app.AccountApplication >./logs/service-account.log &
```

**Jenkins pipeline:**

```
stage('UPLOAD') {
    agent{node { label "TEST" }}
    steps {
        sh "./test.sh"
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all you run `test.sh` in your Pipeline not `run.sh`. Also define *not work*. Any error?

Comment: thank you Jens,service not run is  because of export JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe,when shell Finished,jenkins will kill that.